# How to have multiple return values returned together within Powershell runspace threads?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, runspace

How can I have the second `$scriptBlock` work as the first `$scriptBlock` does? The differences between the 2 are that the first one returns a single object from a command and the second one should return an array of objects from multiple commands?

To test this code you only need fill in the server names for `$servers` and an Exchange powershell hyperlink for `$connectionUri` and alternate between commenting out the first `$scriptBlock` (working) and the second `$scriptBlock` (not working).

Thanks

```
cls

Write-Host "Aynchronous";

# Create session state
$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();

$myString = "this is session state!";
$sessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault();
$sessionstate.Variables.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList "myString" ,$myString, "example string"));

# Create runspace pool consisting of $numThreads runspaces
$minimumAmountOfThreads = 1;
$maximumAmountOfThreads= 15;
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 15, $sessionState, $Host);
$RunspacePool.Open();

$servers = @("server1","server2","server3");
$connectionUri = "http://[something]/powershell";

$threads = @();
$Jobs = @();
$asynchronousThreadCount = 0;
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $scriptBlock = "import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber; get-exchangeserver $server;"; # working
    #$scriptBlock = "import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber; $returnValue = @(); $returnValue += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; return $returnValue;"; # NOT working
        #$scriptBlock = "import-module 'activedirectory'; Get-ADDomain"; # working
    #$scriptBlock = "import-module 'activedirectory'; $returnValue = @(); $returnValue += Get-ADDomain; return $returnValue;" # NOT working

    $asynchronousThreadCount ++;
    $runspaceObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
        Invoker = $null
    }
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.RunSpacePool = $runspacePool;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddScript($scriptBlock) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddArgument($c) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Invoker = $runspaceObject.Runspace.BeginInvoke();
    $threads += $runspaceObject;
    $elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;

    Write-Host "A synchronous created thread $asynchronousThreadCount " $elapsed;
}

Write-Host $threads.Count;
Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Waiting.." -NoNewline;
Do {
   Write-Host "." -NoNewline;
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
} While ( $runspaceObject.Invoker.IsCompleted -contains $false ); 

$resultsAsynchronous = @();

foreach ($tr in $threads)
{
    $resultsAsynchronous += $tr.Runspace.EndInvoke($tr.Invoker);
    $tr.Runspace.Dispose();
}
$procCountMultiThread = $resultsAsynchronous.Count;

$runspacePool.Close();
$runspacePool.Dispose();

$elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;
Write-Host "Multithread elapsed time: $elapsed";
Write-Host "Asynchronous return value count " $resultsAsynchronous.Count;
$resultsAsynchronous #| fl fqdn, AdminDisplayVersion;
```

Comment: Please be more specific that "not working". Have you checked `$tr.Runspace.Streams.Error`?

Comment: Yes I have, there are no errors. The only thing returned with the one labeled not working is the pssession hash table that has the "module", "name" and "exported commands". With the working version, you receive that hash table and the cmdlet return value as well. I tried to make it so that you could try the code, if you do so you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I don't have an exchange environment to test against

Comment: If you have an AD environment, I was able to duplicate the same behavior with this code in place of the "$scriptBlock" variables in the original code `code` #$scriptBlock = "import-module 'activedirectory'; Get-ADDomain"; # working
     $scriptBlock = "import-module 'activedirectory'; $returnValue = @(); $returnValue += Get-ADDomain; return $returnValue;" # NOT working

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `$` when defining your scriptblocks using double-quotes:

```
$scriptBlock = "import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber; $returnValue = @(); $returnValue += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; return $returnValue;"; # NOT working
```

ends up as the string

```
import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri ) -AllowClobber;  = @();  += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server ; return ;
```

Escape the relevant variable sigils with `` ` ``:

```
$scriptBlock = "import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber; `$returnValue = @(); `$returnValue += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; return `$returnValue;";
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, would you mind sharing how you troubleshot that to figure out the answer?